# How can I extract list from list in prolog?

Tags: prolog

Please Can anyone help in writing a function?  Here are my requirements:

*Input:* a list of indexes (such as `[0,1,0]`) and a list of values
*Output:* the corresponding values, in the order provided by the list of indexes

What I envision would be something like this:

```
extract_list([0.1.0],[a,b,c],X)
```

This should bind `X` to `[a,b,a]`

note:
'a' index is 0
'b' index is 1
'a' index is 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using lambdas and maplist:

```
extract_list(Is, L, Vs) :-
   maplist(L+\I^nth0(I,L), Is, Vs).
```

or more verbosely:

```
extract_list(Is, L, Vs) :-
   maplist(L+\I^V^nth0(I,L,V), Is, Vs).
```

or more verbosely:

```
list_index_value(L, I, V) :-
   nth0(I, L, V).

extract_list(Is, L, Vs) :-
   maplist(list_index_value(L), Is, Vs).
```

or more verbosely (use only if health-care covers CTS):

```
extract_list([], _L, []).
extract_list([I|Is], L, [V|Vs]) :-
   nth0(I, L, V),
   extract_list(Is, L, Vs).
```